# How to show home page whenever i click first Tabbar button in iphone

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, iphone-sdk-4.1

In my application i am using UITabbarController and in a homepage I have 4 buttons and they lead to a their respective views. If i click another button in tabbar and again click the home button, It shows the view which was last viewed not the actual home page. How to show the home page whenever i click the home tabbar button.

plz help...
 thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to always load a particular tab after the user clicks the home button on the iOS device and reopens your app?

The easiest way is in

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

Set the selectedIndex for the index you want to show up as selected in your UITabBarController object.